# Handling many states asynchronously in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am currently learning how to create bigger javascript projects and stumbled on an problem (Question below)

Here is a scenario:

```
var dialogOpen = 0;
var purchaseMode = 0;
var editMode = 0;
var currentlyEditing = 0;
var helper = 0;
```

I mean just an example of some flags that could be used for some purpose, all async of course. My question is, is there a better way to handle a crazy amount of states that need to be handled without having to spread state changes all over my application in an inconsistent manner?

```
if (!editMode) { 
    editMode = 1;
   // Let the user edit all text
} else {
   editMode = 1;
}


if (target == purchaseButton) {
   purchaseMode = 1;
}

if (purchaseMode) {
   // allow purchases
}
```

I mean this is a small example, its harmless but I hope you understand the predicament im in. Imagine a software with 10.000 lines of code. Oh crap that would be pretty evil and extremely hard to maintain. **What are some best practices to solve such a problem for larger scale programs?**

Comment: The solution is called **object oriented design**.  Encapsulate a flag/mode only inside an object.  Make all operations that need access to that flag be methods of that object.  Then outside code just calls the methods, the methods examine that flag and do the right thing.  The rest of the world doesn't need to know about the flag.

Comment: How can some flags be async?